# How to get text in a data- element to show up in another div on hover of a specific 'item' on the page

Tags: javascript, html

Example:

This page has only two parts a header and content. In the content there are 100 links. (way more in my case). Each link has 4 data- attributes. data-name, data-time, data-date, and data-zip. Each link in the content has these 4 attributes and each is different. How can I make it so that when i hover over a link with these data- attributes the data for that link appears in a div in my header? So each new link I hover over that data will appear in the header.

I've looked at the stuff on "popunders" but I'm not sure that's what I need.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you can use JQuery. Below steps can work for you.

Step 1 : You can use on mouse over on the anchor
    `$( "#id_anchor" ).mouseover(function() {
    });`

Step 2: `$(this).data('data-name');`

This will go under the event, Get other values and concatenate them

Step 3: `$('#Output-div').html(value) // show the concatenated values in the output DIV`

Whole code will be like below

```
var divStr;
$( "#id_anchor" ).mouseover(function() {
  divStr += $(this).data('data-name'); 
  divStr += $(this).data('data-time'); 
  divStr += $(this).data('data-date'); 
  divStr += $(this).data('data-zip'); 
  // you can also format the data here like the way you want
});
$('#Output-div').html(divStr)
```

Comment: Anyway you might be able to show a jsfiddle? Sorry, I am so new to JS.

Comment: Can you create me one jsfiddle with your html. I can then update the js part.

Comment: Sure can, Give me just a sec, Thanks,

Comment: Had to make a quick example as my code is crazy long. I can integrate it though as I'm sure this is a simple task once I see it. Here is the fiddle. Thanks http://jsfiddle.net/hv97S/

Comment: Update the fiddle. Please check it now

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Is there a way to keep the default state/contnt of the header whe not moused over? In this case, once you mouse over a link then leave it the data from the last moused over link remains in the header.

Comment: Check it now - http://jsfiddle.net/hv97S/10/   . Added for name. It will be default with out mouse over. Later set a text that you want instead of hardcoded 'Default'

Answer (score 1):

try with this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xcghz/2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a ;
    var header = $("#header");
    $(".link").mouseover(function(){
        a = "Name : "+$(this).data('name') + " Date : "+$(this).data('date')+ " Time : "+$(this).data('time')+ " Zip : "+$(this).data('zip');
        $("#header").text(a);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $("#header").text("Hello World!");
    });
});
```

1. Keep all links with a common `class` so selection will be easy.
2. Trigger a `mouseover()` function to get those link's data attributes
3. Concat it to a `div` or show it to a header in a your case

Comment: Is there a way to keep the header in a default state when not moused over or when the mouse leaves the link? IE: a welcome message in the header that always show till a link is moused over.

Comment: Thanks for your answer they both worked just fine. Can't vote you due to rep tho. But thanks!

Comment: @user2106354 s there is attach `.mouseleave()`

Comment: @user2106354 that's okay :) check my updated answer.